# Tomcat7, unexpected shutdown

Tags: tomcat

there

I had in trouble due to tomcat's unexpected shutdown.
I've checked this is not related with

> `"Out of memory"`

Catalina Log file just says

> "INFO: Cookies: Invalid cookie. Value not a token or quoted value 
>   Note: further occurrences of Cookie errors will be logged at DEBUG
>   level"

I could not find any clue about shutdown.

What could be caused to the tomcat shutdown except of `"out of memory"`?